# Notification when a shopping cart is abandoned

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

How to create a notification when a shopping cart is dropped ?

I wish that the user who has not completed his / her order, receives an email 1 day after, to tell him that he has a basket in progress.

I think this should be possible with the "Rules" module.

Thank you

Comment: Bonjour! Can you think of a way to create a "view" of such carts? FYI: that's a prerequisite of "a" solution I can think of to make it work.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Hello, yes I created a shopping cart view. How to create the rule? I tested the module "Commerce Abandoned Cart Notification", but it is full of bug and works very badly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by trying the existing [Commerce Abandoned Cart Notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_notification) module. This module was specifically designed to send abandoned cart notifications.

> This module allows you to notify your customers by email about their abandoned their cart.
>
> *Abandoned Shopping Cart mailings generate more than 55% more conversion compared to regular email campaigns. –SeeWhy research (2011)*
>
> Features
>
> - List your customers abandoned carts
> - 100% integration with Commerce VBO
> - Edit the notification email directly from the Rule component